# Custom Post Type parent slug as menu item

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, menus, taxonomy

I created a Custom Post Type with the slug "Sell". I want to add this to my menu set up in **Appearence**. But it seems to work only for actual items created with this CPT. But I need the menu link, because "Sell" should be an archive page with all posts created with this CPT. I don't want to hardcode the menu and don't want to use a custom link, because the current class is missing then and I need the current class for "Sell" when I am on a page (the child post so to say) created with the CPT.

I googled extensively but didn't find a solution for that. Is it possible per se and how? I am using the Types plugin (http://wp-types.com/) btw. In the settings I enabled the **show_in_nav_menus** option, of course.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To show a page at the custom post type 'home' you need to create a regular page with that slug. You can then add the page to the menu.

I think I saw this in a different answer somewhere, but can't find it right now.